# How can one find the parameters of N-fold convolution in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, parameters, convolution

I have an interesting problem which is about convolution of K vectors with each other. All elements of the K-1 vectors are known. For example:

```
v1,v2,...vk,...,vK
```

and all elememts of all vectors, except vk, are known, and only two neighboring elements of vk are parameters. For example:

```
v1=[p1 p2 4 5];
v2=[1 4 2 3 2 1];
v3=[1 1 1 2];
v4=[2 2 1 3 4];
```

The question is the following:

Let ''v'' be the convolution of v1,v2,v3,v4, i.e.(assuming conv works for symbolically)

```
v=conv(v1,v2); 
v=conv(v,v3);
v=conv(v,v4);
```

Then, each element of v can be written as follows:

```
v(n)=a0(n)+a1(n)*p1+a2(n)*p2
```

> Example: Lets have two vectors

```
v1=[1, 1,1]
v2=[p1,p2,1]
```

Then

```
v=[p1,p1+p2,p1+p2+1,p2+1,1]
```

As a result we have

```
a0=[0,0,1,1,1], a1=[1,1,1,0,0], a2=[0,1,1,1,0]
```

So a0 are the constants of each element of v, a1 are the multiplicants of p1 and a2 are the multiplicants of p2

I want to have an efficient algorithm which can calculate a0(n), a1(n) and a2(n). In the next iteration I have shift of the parameters but the same problem. After one shift I will have

```
v1=[3 p1 p2 5];
v2=[1 4 2 3 2 1];
v3=[1 1 1 2];
v4=[2 2 1 3 4];
```

after two shifts:

```
v1=[3 1 p1 p2];
v2=[1 4 2 3 2 1];
v3=[1 1 2 2];
v4=[2 2 1 3 4];
```

after three shifts:

```
v1=[3 1 4 5];
v2=[p1 p2 2 3 2 1];
v3=[1 1 1 2];
v4=[2 2 1 3 4];
```

this continues until

```
v1=[3 1 4 5];
v2=[1 4 2 3 2 1];
v3=[1 1 1 2];
v4=[2 2 1 p1 p2];
```

at each iteration I need to obtain a0(n), a1(n) and a2(n). So in total there are 15 iterations and at each iteration I will obtain 3 vectors. Hence, in total I need to obtain a matrix which has 15 rows and 3xlength(a0) columns.

```
 i=1 -> a0_i,a1_i,a2_i, for i=1,...,15.
```

> My idea was to define all elements of all vectors as parameters p1,...pK. Then convolve all of them just one time symbolically. This gives v(p1,...,pN). Then at each iteration, except for the two neighboring parameters of interest, I can give all other values and I can evaluate v for example:

```
v(p1,p2,1,3 4,....,2)
```

> after this, I can check every element of v for
>
> v(n)=a0(n)+a1(n)*p1+a2(n)*p2
>
> and extract a0(n), a1(n) and a2(n).
>
> First of all I am not sure whether this is efficient or not. Because, at each iteration I must evaluate the whole symbolic thing v(p1,p2,1,3 4,....,2), which may be unnecessary since I have just simple iteration of the parameters. Second I dont know how one could do convolution of K vectors symbolically, or wheter it is a good or a bad idea.

Another idea is to see that apart from one vector, all vectors do not contain any parameter. So one can first convolve these vectors with conv function and obtain v*. Then, a1(n) and a2(n) seem to be just the elements of v*, just one is a shifted one of the other. Here is what I did on a paper as an example (p1, p2 are parameters, p3, p4 are known and a1,..,a13 are the result of convolution of known vectors):

[image]

This approach seems more clear but at each iteration, one must convolve K-1 vectors. Hence it seems that one needs to make alot of calculations and probably many calculations are the same with the previous iteration. Therefore, it seems to me not so efficient.

> Question: Given K arbitarty vectors, each having arbitrary lengths, how can one calculate the above mentioned vectors efficiently?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly `a0`, `a1` and `a2` are vectors that have the same length as `v` right ? But in this case all your equations system will be underdetermined so there will be an infinite numbers of possible `a0`, `a1` and `a2`. If i've misunderstood the question, please can you add the solution of one specific case.

Comment: Also I do not understand your sentence `let ''v'' be the convolution of v1,v2,v3,v4`. A convolution can only imply two functions (continuous) or two vectors (discrete). So how  can `v` be the convolution of 4 vectors ?

Comment: yes, a0, a1, a2 are vectors which have the same length as v. There is no equation system here. We are looking index by index. So assume you convolve [1, 1,1] with [p1,p2,1]. Then v=[p1,p1+p2,p1+p2+1,p2+1,1]. Then we have a0=[0,0,1,1,1], a1=[1,1,1,0,0], a2=[0,1,1,1,0].  So a0 are the constants of each element of v, a1 are the multiplicants of p1 and a2 are the multiplicants of p2. Is it clear now?

Comment: v=conv(v1,v2); v=conv(v,v3); and finally v=conv(v,v4); So convolution of all these 4 with each other.

Comment: Ok yeah, now it's clear, feel free to add this information in your question. With only one parameter you could have use complex number (with `p1 = 1i`). Then splitting the real part and the imaginary part could have solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conv` do not support symbolic math. So we have to use another method.

One solution could be to split the vector containing the two parameters into three part.

If we have `v1 = [p1 p2 4 5]`

we could create `v1_split`:

```
 v1_split = [1 0 0 0;   %p1
             0 1 0 0;   %p2
             0 0 4 5];
```

Then we can recursively use `conv2` to solve the problem:

```
sol = conv2(conv2(conv2(v1_split,v2),v3),v4)
```

It will output a `3xlength(a)` vector where the first line is a0, the second a1 and the last one a2.

Of course instead of using `conv2(conv2(conv2(...` we can use a recursive function:

```
function r = rconv2(x)
   if length(x) == 1 
      r = x{1};
   else
     r = conv2(x{1},rconv2(x(2:end)));
   end
 end
```

So now we can use something like:

```
%input vector for step 1
v ={[1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0; 0 0 4 5],[1 4 2 3 2 1],[1 1 1 2],[2 2 1 3 4]} %{v1_split,v2,v3,v4}

%recursive convolution
sol = rconv2(v)
```

**EDIT**, improvement according to @Seyhmus comment:

```
%Initial cell array of vectors
v ={[1 3 4 5],[1 4 2 3 2 1],[1 1 1 2],[2 2 1 3 4]} %{v1,v2,v3,v4}

%recursive convolution (need to be run only once)
allconv = rconv2(v)

%Example for step 1
%Deconv allconv with v{1}
dec = deconv(allconv,v{1})

%Compute v1_split
...

%Getting the solution using 2D convolution with v1_split:
sol = conv2(dec,v1_split)
```

Comment: I think 1D is would be a better option in terms of computational complexity. or? For example:  vx=conv(v2,v3);  vx=conv(vx,v4); then  conv([ 0 0 4 5],vx) will give a0, similarly conv([ 1 0 0 0],vx)  and conv([ 0 1 0 0],vx). I will still need to obtain vectors of v1_split for the next shifts. For example when I have v1=[3 p1 p2 5]; will I have then v1_split = [0 1 0 0;   0 0 1  0;   3 0 0  5];?

Comment: It all depend on your problem, of course you will save a few operations, but if you have only 10 vectors you will loose the simplicity of the code above for a time saving of only a few milliseconds.

Comment: I see. Actually this question is a toy example. Normally I have at least 1000 vectors each has a length 10. This means that I will have in total 10.000 shifts. At each shift, I will have 1000 times 2D convolution. This means in total I will have 10 million convolutions. This is just one iteration of my big program. I may need upto 100s of iterations for convergence. In total I will need 1 billion convolutions. This is just for 1000 vectors. If I have 1 million vectors, I wont get any result. This way of handling the problem seems to be scaling very badly. This solution is my 2. way with figure

Comment: I think I am wrong. This can be done much efficiently. First we convolve all 1000 vectors. Then we deconvolve the vector that has the parameters inside. After that do the convolutions as you said in your answer for each iteration. So inside one vector, each shift will cost only 1 convolution. After one vector is finished, before we go to the next vector we need to devonvolve this vector with the overall convolution of 1000 vectors which was already calculated. Using this vector we can go again 9 more iterations. So in total one needs 10.000 convolutions for the whole process.

Comment: However the lengths of the convolved vectors are 9001 and 10 at each iteration...

Comment: Ho yeah, using a deconvolution is a good idea, I've edited my answer.